# How to display app icons on second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, taskbar, icons, windows-11-v22h2

I just updated from Windows 10 to Windows 11 today (a few minutes ago).

I have all of these icons at the bottom right corner of my main screen. Before the upgrade, I could just drag the taskbar from my main screen to my second screen and that's it. The app icons in the taskbar will be displayed on the second monitor.

However, Windows 11 does not allow me to drag from my main screen to my second screen anymore. I tried googling it but found no solution. Therefore, I'm posting it here hoping someone knows how to do it.

Image for reference: "Taskbar app icons"

[image: taskbar app icons]

**Edited**: I do not want to change my main screen.

Comment: Windows 11 has a poor re-write of the windows explorer with far less functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Currently as of the date of post, there is no way to achieve this with the built-in user settings of windows 11.